# `waitForEnabled()` says "selector needs to be typeof `string`" even though string was passed

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I was originally using the `mocha` command line tool to run my tests and they were working fine.  I switched to using the `wdio` command to run my tests.  My tests now throw an error with this line of code:

```
browser.waitForEnabled('#div_id');
```

With this error:

```
Promise was rejected with the following reason: Error: selector needs to be typeof `string`
running chrome
Error: Promise was rejected with the following reason: Error: selector needs to be typeof `string`
    at elements() - isEnabled.js:18:17
    at isEnabled() - waitForEnabled.js:37:22
```

This was working fine until I started using `wdio` (specifically I run `wdio --spec path/to/file.js`).  I've run the `typeof` function on the selector in question and verified that it is, in fact, a string.

The div in question looks like this:

```
<div class="highlight" id="div_id">
A fair bit of content goes here.
</div>
```

Why am I seeing this error? How do I fix it?

`waitForEnabled()` documentation => http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitForEnabled.html

`wdio` documentation => http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/gettingstarted.html

**Update:**

I've tried adding a timeout to the `waitForEnabled()` function.  Since I've done so, it sometimes fails, and sometimes does not.  More often it fails though.

Comment: can you please share the peace of code for that #div_id. Did you try to use timeout for waitForEnabled ?

Comment: @k185 you want the result of the selector?

Comment: Using a timeout (as in `waitForEnabled('#div_id', 9000);`) fails with the same error.  However, it waits to fail until the specified time has elapsed.

Comment: no, part of div that you are targeting

Comment: @k185 . I've edited my question to include the div itself.  Lmk if you want more info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not marking this as the answer because I have no idea why it works.  But passing in all of the optional params to `waitForEnabled()` makes it work just fine.

As in:
`waitForEnabled('#div_id');` Fails.  Wheras:

`waitForEnabled('#div_id', 99999, false);` works without errors.

Comment: did you change the timeout value in wdio.conf.js file? or do have this value in that file at all?

Comment: `waitforTimeout: 10000,` (in wdio.conf.js)

Comment: it is not gonna help but I think the problem is that, since the 10 sec timeout is pretty short some times. According to my tries I always add 
mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 999999
    },
this timeout to wdio.conf.js file

Answer (score -1):

The fact that you're passing milliseconds & the false option should not make the test pass.

I'd suggest using some of the other waitFor commands, like `waitForVisible()` or `waitForExist()`, because I'm assuming this is what you really want from the code example you gave above. The `waitForEnabled()` command waits for a field that had a `disabled` html attribute, to not have it anymore. You can read more on that here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp.

Comment: I am aware. The intended behavior is to test that this div stops existing.  I'm asking why I'm seeing this error.

Comment: Alright. I'm just suggesting that you use `waitForExist()` instead, because `waitForExist(null, true)` waits for the default amount of milliseconds provided in the wdio.conf.js until the element stops existing, and the `waitForEnabled()` does something else entirely.